# How to show all siblings on :hover in pure CSS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Need to select all sibling `<li>` elements on hover. Tried [accepted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8335673/selecting-siblings-on-hover) but it is not working. [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/656kqjvp/)

```css
.menu {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;;
    background-color: #777;
}
.menu li {
    float: none;
    display: none;
}
.menu li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #bbb;
}
.menu li a:hover {
    color: #fff;
}
.menu .btn {
        display: block;
        cursor: pointer;
}
.menu li:hover ~ .menu li{/*ON THIS HOVER NOT SHOWING ALL SIBLIING LIs*/
        display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<!--NEED SOLUTION WITHOUT ALTERING HTML -->
<ul class="menu">
            <li class="btn"><a>&#9776;</a></li>
            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a>
                
            <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="/">Sub Menu</a></li>
            <li><a href="/portfolio">Sub Menu</a></li>
            </ul>
                
            </li>
</ul>
<!--NEED SOLUTION WITHOUT ALTERING HTML -->
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is the selector:

```
.menu li:hover ~ .menu li
```

A hidden element can't be hovered-over, which means that `li:hover` is never going to match an element. Also, the general-sibling combinator is trying to find (subsequent) siblings that are `<li>` elements descending from sibling `.menu` elements. Which matches no elements in the page.

Converting that to the following selector:

```
.menu:hover li ~ li
```

```css
.menu {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  ;
  background-color: #777;
}
.menu li {
  float: none;
  display: none;
}
.menu li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #bbb;
}
.menu li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
.menu .btn {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.menu:hover li ~ li {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!--NEED SOLUTION WITHOUT ALTERING HTML -->
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="btn"><a>&#9776;</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="/">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="/portfolio">Portfolio</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a>

    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li><a href="/">Sub Menu</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="/portfolio">Sub Menu</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </li>
</ul>
<!--NEED SOLUTION WITHOUT ALTERING HTML -->
```

works; that said it will - because of the general sibling combinator - match only those `<li>` elements with a preceding `<li>` sibling, which means it will, and *can*, never show the *first* `<li>`.

So, instead, I'd suggest using:

```
.menu:hover li
```

```css
.menu {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  ;
  background-color: #777;
}
.menu li {
  float: none;
  display: none;
}
.menu li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #bbb;
}
.menu li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
.menu .btn {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.menu:hover li {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!--NEED SOLUTION WITHOUT ALTERING HTML -->
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="btn"><a>&#9776;</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="/">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="/portfolio">Portfolio</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a>

    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li><a href="/">Sub Menu</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="/portfolio">Sub Menu</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </li>
</ul>
<!--NEED SOLUTION WITHOUT ALTERING HTML -->
```

Comment: Yes, that's because the first `<li>`, of `class="btn"`, is already specifically shown. in the rules applied to the  `.menu .btn` selector.